# Can we extract data from Qlik sense through the Rest API?

Tags: qliksense

I have to extract data from Qlik Sense through the Rest api Call  hence I have explored and haven't found any solution.  is it possible to do the Rest call to Qlik sense app to extract data ?

Comment: Hi qliksense is solution to consume data (BI) so it displays what is imported. However there are possibility to write own extension or use one of which are ready on the market.

Comment: Please provide the names of extensions to connect Qlik Data model to read the data

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no REST API allowing to access data inside an application.
There is a Javascript and .Net SDK to use the Engine API and thus connect to data .

There is a also various REST API to manage application, streams, tasks, users...

However, if you want to get access to Qlik data, I suggest you add STORE commands in your load script to dump the tables to text or CSV files, making them easily readable after.

Comment: "There is a also various REST API to manage application, streams, tasks, users..."
Could you point me to the relevant documentation for this?
I'm using a on-prem instance of Qlik Sense

Answer (score -1):

Qlik sense does not provide an API to expose the data in Qlik to other applications.
Because we did need this functionality (for instance to expose data from Qlik to Rapid Application Development platforms like Mendix) we developed a custom application that can help. see https://ddcgroup.com/qlik-data-extractor for more info.
With this tool, you can define the rest webservices that you need (including aggregation etc) which can be called to extract data from Qlik.